# IBAction not getting called from Subviews button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, hierarchy

So I spent my whole evening trying to solve my issue that is clicking Button located in UIViewController will not trigger IBAction.

### My situation

I'm building my app using storyboard and my main ViewController is a TabBarViewController. One of the items of said TabBarViewController is, let's call it `MainViewController`.

Behind `MainViewController` there is `BackgroundViewController` which contains only camera preview and nothing else.

`BackgroundViewController` was added inside `MainViewController` as follows:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
BackgrondViewController *bckgController = (BackgrondViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"background"];

[self.view addSubview:bckgController.view];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bckgController.view];
```

Everything works so far and I'm mentioning it becouse that might be relevant.

## TopController

Now I want to add another ViewController to the `MainViewController`, this time on top. Let's call top view controller as `TopViewController`.

So first I instatiate it like this:

```
TopViewController *topController = (TopViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"top"];
topController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I added clearColor because there is need for that in my app and its **confirmed** that this changes nothing (trust me, I tried).

Okay now I add freshly created view as follows (we are still inside  `MainViewController`)

```
 [self.view addSubview:topController.view];
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:topController.view];
```

And it in fact does display transparent view with just a button in the center.

## The Issue

No matter what I try I cannot make the button call its IBAction method.

## Known facts and what I tried

- `TopViewController` is actually on top of `MainViewController` views, I checked that by getting all subviews of `MainViewController`, taking the last element and comparing it to `TopViewController`'s view.
- IBAction is correctly linked to the Button I need to click (confirmed via storyboard and mousing-over methods outlet)
- Adding `TopViewController` to TabBar works just fine, the Button does its job
- The Button is visually clickable and it performs default animation when clicked
- Setting `topController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES` doesn't work
- Adding single tap handler on `TopViewController` and clicking anywhere on screen doesn't work, however adding it to `MainViewController` does work (clicking anywhere on screen triggers defined action despite `TopViewController` being on top)
- All sizes, id's and corresponding classes are verified
- `viewDidLoad` of `TopViewController`is getting called

Please help me get out of this jam. Thanks!

Comment: I will NOT answer your question, but instead I want you to know that putting a ViewController's view and showing as a subview like you did is not a good practice.Instead, You should use a containerViewController or make the BackgroundViewController a subclass of UIView, not UIViewController (I think your case fits here). Hope it helps you anyway.

Comment: @FormigaNinja thanks for the input, SDK I use for my BackgroundViewController forces me to show UIViewController as a subview unfortunately.  The top view controller however is being displayed for a few seconds only one time per user so its not that big of a deal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you retaining `topController` by using an instance variable or property?

A simple way to do this is to create a property in your MainViewController.h file.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) TopViewController *topViewController;
@end
```

Or at the top of your MainViewController.m file

```
@interface MainViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) TopViewController *topViewController;
@end
```

Then set the property any time after you created it.

`self.topViewController = topController;`

**Explanation**

`-[UIView addSubview:]` retains the view, but not the view controller. If you do not retain the view controller, then ARC will release the view controller at the end of the function. You can verify this by overriding `-[TopViewController dealloc]`. When you press the button, it tries to send a message to a now `nil` view controller.

Comment: I see where this is going, I'm coming from android developement and don't quite get how to fix this by retaining the view controller, could you elaborate?

Comment: Oh! Basically, you would be creating an instance variable in your MainViewController class, then assigning the topController to that, basically making it a class member. I've updated my answer with the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked! But is this a good practice to set a strong viewcontroller property to another view controller?

Comment: As long as it's a one way relationship, it's fine. UITabBarController and UINavigationController actually both retain their view controllers strongly. This ensures that the children view controller do not get destroyed while the parent still exists and depends on them.